# Load local translations in i18next having no webserver on a static HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, internationalization, i18next

I have a plain HTML file with the following javascript written on it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" type="text/javascript">
function setLang() {
    var lang = $('#lang').find(":selected").val();

    i18next.use(i18nextHttpBackend).init({
        lng: lang,
        fallbackLng: 'en',
        defaultNs: 'translations',
        ns: 'translations',
        backend: {
            loadPath: 'http://localhost/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
        },
    }, function (err, t) {
        jqueryI18next.init(i18next, $);
        $('.container').localize();
    });
}
</script>
```

Inside the `locales` subdirectory, translation files for each language is kept as shown below:

```
└── locales
    ├── en
    │   └── translations.json
    ├── de
    │   └── translations.json
    └── zh
        └── translations.json
```

Just for testing these translations files, I kept them on a local server and it works.

**How do load these local translation files without having a webserver?**

PS: I found the following two similar questions [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58604348/1175065) and [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63245766/1175065). However, they are related to ReactJS.

Answer (score 0):

You need to publish all your html and json files to a static webserver, like Github-Pages or similar…

Alternatively, add the translations on init directly: https://www.i18next.com/how-to/add-or-load-translations#add-on-init

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, there is no internet connectivity. Furthermore, a local web server is not allowed as well!!!

Comment: Then there is no chance you can access another file beside the html file... but you can add the resources on init: https://www.i18next.com/how-to/add-or-load-translations#add-on-init

Comment: Yeah. I read about adding the resources on init. However, is there any other way to fetch the local JSON from HTML?

Comment: No, the browser CORS prevents this.

Comment: I made it work by disabling CORS. HOWEVER, IT IS NOT RECOMMENDED.